# Javascript adding variable and number within a String

Tags: javascript, string

My problem: i want to add 1 to a variable (row) within a String.

This won't work:

```
function checkIfWon(col, row, color) {
         alert(document.querySelector('[col="' + col + '"][row="' + row+1 + '"]').getAttribute("color"));
}
```

Error in Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

But this code gives me the color:

```
function checkIfWon(col, row, color) {
         let newRow = row+1;
         alert(document.querySelector('[col="' + col + '"][row="' + newRow + '"]').getAttribute("color"));
    }
```

so how can i add row + 1 within the String?
Thanks.

Comment: your issue is that `row="' + row+1 + '"]` isn't adding 1 to row, it's concatenating

Comment: @NickParsons I know, so how I can I add 1 to row in my String?

Comment: try `... [row="' + (row+1) + '"]'`

Comment: why not just use ` `[col="${col}"][row="${row+1}"]` ` template string

Comment: @NickParsons (row+1) solved my Problem, thx

Comment: In javascript
`1 + 1 == 2 // addition
'1' + '1' == '11' // concatenation
1 + '1'  == '11' // concatenation
1 + 1 + '1' == '21' // addition, concatenation
1 + 1 + '1' + 1 + 1 == '2111' // addition, concatenation, concatenation`

i.e, Once String concatenation starts, everything ahead is concatenated as string.

Comment: You don't exactly have to use template litterals but it's cleaner that way. Alternatively you could just use `(...)` between the math you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

for contact

```
alert(document.querySelector(`[col="${col}"][row="${row}1"]`).getAttribute("color"));
```

for sum

```
alert(document.querySelector(`[col="${col}"][row="${+row+1}"]`).getAttribute("color"));
```

Comment: This will give the result that OP wants to *avoid*

Comment: thanks, I didn't get it clear, updated answer